# How do I create a windows service for authentication that custom web applications can use to authenticate AD users?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, authorization

My company is moving to a more centralized model, and we want to have a service that checks the user logged into the system again groups in AD.  The service should act like a plug-in, in that when we create or update an application, we should be able to add the service to the application with little to no configuration.  I have some experience with Active Directory, but I just need to figure out the best way to start the project.

Comment: what type of project is this for?

Comment: We're a fairly small company with some old applications that we are going to rewrite to C# MVC5 web apps.  Want the users to be able to go to a webpage, and if they belong to the correct AD group, be authorized to use the application.  But we want it to be something that we can plug into any application.

Comment: use the code in my answer below and that will help you, its code i use in production applications and works flawlessly

Comment: but if youre working on an MVC application you actually have a much simpler way of doing this

Comment: Either of the two actions here should help you.  If not then take a look at this link here http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/custom-authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you have given a response that this is an MVC application.  You can do something like this:

```
[Authorize(Role = "role 1, role2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //your code here
  return //your return object 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a class file I created that will do that checking for you and more and should do everything you need.

```
public class IsUserInRole
{

    public bool IsInGroup(string groupName)
    {
        var myIdentity = GetUserIdWithDomain();
        var myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(myIdentity);
        return myPrincipal.IsInRole(groupName);
    }

    public  WindowsIdentity GetUserIdWithDomain()
    {
        var myIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        return myIdentity;
    }

    public string GetUserId()
    {
        return GetUserInformation().Name;
    }

    public string GetUserDisplayName()
    {
        return GetUserInformation().DisplayName;

    }

    public UserPrincipal GetUserInformation()
    {
        var id = GetUserIdWithDomain().Name.Split('\\');

        var dc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, id[0]);
        return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(dc, id[1]);
    }

    public UserPrincipal GetUserInformation(string domain, string lanId)
    {
        var dc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
        return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(dc, lanId);
    }


}
```